# ASP.NET Web App Logging using Health Monitoring not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, logging, health-monitoring

I am using VS2005 C# 2.0 and SQL Server 2005.

I am referring to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650305.aspx) guide on configuring Health Monitoring.

At the end of the guide, there will be a button on *Default.aspx* and on_Click of the button, a new record will be inserted into my SQL table.

However, when my button is pressed, there is no record inserted in the table.

I am unsure of what the error as there are no error messages shown, so I guess the only way is to trial and error on where I have gone wrong.

**P.S.** I am unable to compile `MyWebEvents` class library because there is no output. In my main web application, I added reference dll from the *bin* folder of my *MyWebEvents* project file. Is the DLL i referenced valid for use, or is there a step I missed in compiling?

Below are the codes which I ran, with reference to the microsoft website:

---

`MyCriticalEvent.cs` in **MyWebEvents** class library:

```
namespace MyWebEvents
{
public class MyCriticalEvent : WebAuditEvent
{
    private string userID;
    private string authType;
    private bool isAuthenticated;

    public MyCriticalEvent(string msg, object eventSource, int eventCode)
        : base(msg, eventSource, eventCode)
    {
        // Obtain the HTTP Context and store authentication details
        userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        authType = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType;
        isAuthenticated = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }

    public MyCriticalEvent(string msg, object eventSource, int eventCode,
                           int eventDetailCode)
        : base(msg, eventSource, eventCode, eventDetailCode)
    {
        userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        authType = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType;
        isAuthenticated = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }

    public override void FormatCustomEventDetails(WebEventFormatter formatter)
    {
        base.FormatCustomEventDetails(formatter);
        formatter.AppendLine("User ID: " + userID);
        formatter.AppendLine("Authentication Type: " + authType);
        formatter.AppendLine("User Authenticated: " +
                              isAuthenticated.ToString());
        formatter.AppendLine("Activity Description: Critical Operation");
    }
} 
}
```

---

`Default.aspx.cs` in **Main Web Application**:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyCriticalEvent testEvent = new MyCriticalEvent(
                                    "Critical Operation Performed",
                                    this,
                                    WebEventCodes.WebExtendedBase + 1);
    testEvent.Raise();
}
}
```

---

`Web.config` in **Main Web Applicatiion**:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=<IP>;Initial Catalog=<DB NAME>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<admin username>;Password=<admin password>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
                <healthMonitoring enabled="true" heartbeatInterval="0">
        <bufferModes>
            <clear/>
            <add name="Logging" maxBufferSize="1000" maxFlushSize="200" urgentFlushThreshold="800" regularFlushInterval="00:05:00" urgentFlushInterval="00:01:00" maxBufferThreads="1"/>
        </bufferModes>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="MySqlWebEventProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" connectionStringName="MySqlConnection" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823" buffer="true" bufferMode="Logging"/>
        </providers>
        <eventMappings>
            <clear/>
            <add name="All Audits" type="System.Web.Management.WebAuditEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
            <add name="All Errors" type="System.Web.Management.WebBaseErrorEvent" startEventCode="0" endEventCode="2147483647"/>
        </eventMappings>
        <profiles>
            <clear/>
            <add name="Audit Logs" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:15"/>
            <add name="Error Logs" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:00:15"/>
        </profiles>
        <rules>
            <clear/>
            <add name="All Audits Default" eventName="All Audits" provider="MySqlWebEventProvider" profile="Audit Logs"/>
            <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="MySqlWebEventProvider" profile="Error Logs"/>
        </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

[image]

---

Table in my database:

[image]

---

Error raised in the Event log if SQL Connection is broken:

`The following exception was thrown by the web event provider 'MySqlWebEventProvider' in the application '/TestLogSite' (in an application lifetime a maximum of one exception will be logged per provider instance):`

---

**Problem Summary**: When `button1` on *Default.aspx.cs* is clicked, no log records were inserted in the `aspnet_WebEvent_Event` table.

May I know which part of my code have I gone wrong or missed out?

Comment: Are you sure that the credentials you're using to connect to SQL are sufficient? Maybe instead of integrated security try using a SQL account and see whether there's any change. Also you could run SQL Profiler against the server while testing to see if anything is actually being sent to SQL.

Comment: @DarthContinent I have change the login using an admin privileged account, however, when i traced the server using SQL Profiler as suggested, I don't see any new events when my button is pressed.

Comment: I guess you must have ran `aspnet_regsql.exe -E -S <ServerName> -A w`. Are there any tables created in the database?

Comment: @AmarPalsapure I have used `aspnet_regsql.exe -S <IP> -U <username> -P <password> -d <DB> -A w`. The tables have been created. Updated my post as well with the screenshot

Comment: Identity the application pool  has access to SQL Server? Did you tried Health Monitoring using VS 2013 - ASP.NET 4.6.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see it right away try disabling buffering

```
<add name="MySqlWebEventProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" connectionStringName="MySqlConnection" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823" buffer="true" bufferMode="Logging"/>
```

change to

```
<add name="MySqlWebEventProvider" type="System.Web.Management.SqlWebEventProvider" connectionStringName="MySqlConnection" maxEventDetailsLength="1073741823" buffer="false" bufferMode="Logging"/>
```

This should stop the delay caused by buffering and you should see the rows appear right away.

Plus you may want to decrease your minInterval on the profiles to something quick like "00:00:01" :)

You can read more about buffering here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178708%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

On a live system it maybe a good idea to leave buffering in place in case you think your SQL server might get overloaded with lots of events firing.

OR

Ive found i can force it save to the log by:

1 : start your project in visual studio
2 : click the button
3 : Stop the project and then start it again
4 : Check in the database you should see an event logged

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I have tried disabling buffering and changing my minInterval, and have also tried your method for forcing it to log, but they doesn't work for me, no records were inserted into the database

Comment: Ok, leave the buffering and intervals as i suggested and look in your event viewer after you do the click.  It maybe something is wrong with your SQL connection.  I tried purposely breaking my SQL connection string and received an Error in the event log Source "ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0" Task Category "Web Event". Stating "The following exception was thrown by the web event provider 'MySqlWebEventProvider' in the application '/' (in an application lifetime a maximum of one exception will be logged per provider instance):....."  have a look and see if you have anything similar.

Comment: And yes, I received a similar error as you once I break my SQL Connection string into an invalid one

Comment: No sorry I meant use the string you were using and check the event log to see if it was erroring (I was only breaking mine on purpose to see what error details would be).  I assume you aren't throwing an error with your original SQL connection string then?

Comment: breaking the string, u mean this string? => "Critical Operation Performed". And yes, there was no error shown with my original SQL Connection string

Comment: Sorry I seemed to have confused the matter, please ignore all my comments about the database connection string.  I was simply attempting to work out if you were having issues connecting to the database.  If you are receiving no errors connecting to the database in the eventlog and have all the buffer settings as i suggested I am not sure what else there could be.  I took your code and setup  a local aspnetdb and when run I am seeing rows inserted. Other than my suggestions about tweakling buffers and mininterval I have made no changes.  I must be missing something but im not sure what, sorry.

Comment: it's alrght. I appreciate your help. I hope it is just permission problem as my code is working on your side.

Answer (score 2):

Try temporarily replacing the SqlWebEventProvider with a [TraceWebEventProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.tracewebeventprovider%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to see if the problem lies in ASP.NET WebEvents or in accessing the SQL database.

The TraceWebEventProvider should avoid permission related problems.

*Updated*

web.config:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <providers>
        <clear/>
            <add name="TraceEventProvider"
        type="System.Web.Management.TraceWebEventProvider, 
          System.Web"
        buffer="false"
        bufferMode=""
        maxEventLength="4096"
        maxSize="4096"
        maxMessagesPerNotification="1"
    />
    </providers>
    ...
    <rules>
        <clear/>
        <add name="All Audits Default" eventName="All Audits" provider="TraceEventProvider" profile="Audit Logs"/>
        <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="TraceEventProvider" profile="Error Logs"/>
    </rules>
    ...
</system.web>
...
```

Comment: can you specify which area I need to replace my SqlWebEventProvider with a TraceWebEventProvider? I have tried to replace part of my web.config with the link you provided, but is having multiple errors, and I'm facing one which says `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies`. Thank you

Comment: thank you for the example. but I am receiving this error `Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` with this line highlighted on the error page: `Line 24:    type="System.Web.Management.TraceWebEventProvider, `

Comment: did you tried using ***System.Web*** with full signature ?